# Finding a particular solution curve and simplifying

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

> Find the equation of the curve that passes through the point $(1, 3)$ and has a slope of $y/x^2$ at any point $(x, y)$.

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y}{x^2}
$$

with the initial condition $y(1) = 3$

$$\int \frac{dy}{dx} = \int \frac{y}{x^2} ,~~~y \ne 0,x > 0
$$

After integrating and solving for $y$, I was able to get

$$y = e^{ - (1/x) + C_1}
$$

but I don't know how the book then gets an answer of

$$y = Ce^{\frac{ - 1}{x}}
$$

I appreciate any assistance in helping me make sense of this simplification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have addition on exponent, you can turn it into multiplication :
$e^{-\frac{1}{x} + c} = e^{c}.e^{-\frac{1}{x}}$.
However $e^{c}$ is just a constant, in indefinite integral constant doesnt matter too much unless if you're asked for the original function, so you can replace $e^{c}$ with another constant $C$

Comment: Thankyou very much!

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

The simplification follows from
$$
y = e^{ - (1/x) + {C_1}} = 
e^{ - (1/x)} e^{C_1},
$$
since
$$
C = e^{C_1}
$$
is just some (positive) constant.